# Get page number of specific item in spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I'm building a web application with spring-data-rest.

I want to show data from a big db-table in a paginated table in my frontend. The table loads asynchronically just the current page from the API. That works all fine and dandy out of the box by just having a repository like

```
public interface KeywordRepository extends JpaRepository<Keyword, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Keyword> {
}
```

Now I want to implement a functionality to jump in my paginated table to the correct page where a certain item is.
Problem is that I don't know on what page that specific item is.

I need some kind of endpoint to tell me the page number of a specific item (by id) according to the current filter- and sorting-parameters. Basically `findPageOfItemById(Long id, Pageable pageable)`.

**How can I get this?**

Since the table is quite big, I don't want to have the whole content in memory.

Comment: Counterquestion: If you store the page requested by the client when you initially load the items, why do you have the need to request the page of that item again? (Of course, the offset can change in the meantime, but what use case do you have?)

Comment: @Glains The id I'm asking for comes from the outside and not from the initial list request.

Comment: To elaborate: The user sees a paginated and asynchronically loaded table with thousands of entries and he may jump to random items and their page just by knowing the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'll answer my own question.

It works quite nice and without loading the whole list into memory as reqested.
But I was still hoping to find a little more *spring-data-rest*y answer.

```
    @GetMapping("/getPositionOfItem/{id}")
    public long getPositionOfItem(@PathVariable String id, @QuerydslPredicate(root = SomeEntity.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        Iterable<SomeEntity> elements = someEntityRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable.getSort());
        return findFirst(elements.iterator(), id);
    }

    private long findFirst(Iterator<SomeEntity> iterator, String id) {
        long index = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next().getId().equals(id)) {
                return index;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Note that I calculate the position of the item. To get the page of the element, we need to divide by the pagesize.